# Is there a way to use .format() syntax when compiling python 3 sqlite 3 cursor.executestript() statements in a safe way?

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite, format

I'm building some Python code that relies on SQLite SQL statements *a lot* (that I read from separate files) with some Python 3 glue code. That meas that I have multi page SQL templates that I feed with parameters in Python and now I wonder how I should go about escaping the variables.

The official way is:
`c.execute("INSERT INTO foo VALUES (?, ?, ?)", (a, b, c))`, which is cute for small SQL snippets, but kinda impractical for multi-page SQL statements (where was that 35th question mark again?).

Something like the `.format()` function syntax would be much more useful, something like: 
`c.executescript("... INSERT INTO foo VALUES ({a}, {b}, {c}); ...".format(a='a', b='b', c="Robert'); DROP TABLE foo; --", ...)`

The actual SQL template string would be read from a file and just be placed as a variable, so `c.executescript(fp.read().format(a='a', b='b', c="Robert'); DROP TABLE foo; --", ...)`. Ultimately this ends up in something like `params={'a':'a', 'b':'b', 'c': "Robert'); DROP TABLE foo; --"}, c.executemany(fp.read().format(**params))`

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQLite supports [named parameters](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#varparam):

```py
c.execute("SELECT :a, :b", {'a': 1, 'b': 'hello'})
```

However, parameters work only with a single SQL statement. For `executescript()`, you have to insert the values directly, and SQL strings must be correctly escaped:

```py
def sql_string(s):
    return "'" + s.replace("'", "''") + "'"

c.executescript(template.format(a=sql_string('Bob...')))
```

Comment: Thanks. Interesting, I came up with something similar, but iterating through parameter dictionary values, and if they are strings replacing single quotes with two quotes and removing null characters. Didn't find a good writeup on what else a good sanitation function would have to filter for. Any idea where I could find something relevant to this?

Comment: There are no special characters except the quote.